# Как в QML передать сотояние перменной в другую вкладку Tab?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick

В слое QML есть TabView в нём есть Switch его id: control.

В id: control находится стояние вкл/выкл.

Как можно control передать в id: tab1 а именно в аргументы вызываемого метода backend.setProperties(control/*передать сюда*/); ?

```
TabView {
    id: tabView
    width: 300
    height: 310

    Tab {
        id: tab
        title: ""
        Rectangle {
            Switch {
                id: control
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: 300
                height: 50
                text: qsTr("")
                checked: false
                onClicked: {
                  backend.setSwitch(control);
                   }
                contentItem: Text {
                    rightPadding: control.indicator.width + control.spacing
                    text: control.text
                    font: control.font
                    opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
                    color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
                    elide: Text.ElideRight
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                }

                indicator: Rectangle {
                    implicitWidth: 48
                    implicitHeight: 26
                    x: control.width - width - control.rightPadding
                    y: parent.height / 2 - height / 2
                    radius: 13
                    color: control.checked ? "#17a81a" : "transparent"
                    border.color: control.checked ? "#17a81a" : "#cccccc"

                    Rectangle {
                        x: control.checked ? parent.width - width : 0
                        width: 26
                        height: 26
                        radius: 13
                        color: control.down ? "#cccccc" : "#ffffff"
                        border.color: control.checked ? (control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b") : "#999999"
                    }
                }

                background: Rectangle {
                    implicitWidth: 100
                    implicitHeight: 40
                    visible: control.down /*|| control.highlighted*/
                    color: control.down ? "#bdbebf" : "#eeeeee"
                }
            }


        }
    }

    Tab {
        id: tab1
        source: "qml.qrc"
        visible: true
        title: ""
        Rectangle {



            Button {
                id: button
                x: 238
                y: 150
                width: 32
                height: 32

                onClicked: {
                    backend.setProperties(control/*передать сюда*/);
                    database.removeRecord();
                    database.inserIntoTable(textField.text, textField1.text);
                }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. просто передавать `control` Вы пробовали, и это не работает?

Comment: @ixSci всё верно.

Comment: Возможно это связано с тем, что неактивный таб ещё не загружен, поэтому доступа к его элеентам нет. Т.е. нужно думать как организовать всё так, чтобы гарантировать существование элемента.

Comment: @ixSci как у меня в примере показана так выдаёт что переменная control не определена или что то в этом роде, делаю вывод что можно было бы воспользоваться глобальными переменными, но в qml их по ходу нет.

Comment: Вы можете сделать `property` у TabView и писать туда всё, что угодно. Так же в QML работают глобальные JS переменные (`var global = "something";`)

Comment: @ixSci а вы может пример привести с ипользованием property у TabVivew так как всё таки глобальные перменные это не совсем хорошо и по возможности стараюсь их избегать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать `property` для TabView:

```
TabView {
    id: tabView
    property Item control
    ...
```

Затем, это свойство нужно где-то выставить, пусть это будет в существующем сигнале (более подходящее место найдёте самостоятельно):

```
onClicked: {
    backend.setSwitch(control);
    tabView.control = control;
}
```

Затем во втором табе:

```
onClicked: {
    backend.setProperties(tabView.control);
```